# How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect Hook to update state when props change

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

my component receives three props. urlText is a string and setSelectedText is a redux Action to update the state from connect() and clearPage which is another redux action to clear the state.

I want to update the state when urlText changes only. and i want to clear the state on unmount.

```
 I get this eslint warning `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: setSelectedText`

 warning `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: clearPage`


const Component = ({ urlText, setSelectedText, clearPage }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedText(urlText);
  }, [urlText]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearPage();
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't have any effect on how your script runs, but the linter is warning you to change it to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedText(
        urlText
    );
}, [setSelectedText, urlText]);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        clearPage();
    };
}, [clearPage]);
```

Though the last can be simplified to:

```
useEffect(() => clearPage, clearPage);
```